# Understanding Implicit AND in Mongoose/MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm struggling to understand the implicit AND when using commas in Mongoose/MongoDB.

Without getting into the details too much of exactly what this query is doing I'll try to make a simple explanation of what I'm trying to understand.

Here's a simple `Post` model with only the relevant field needed for my question:

```
const PostSchema = new Schema({
  likeCount: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0
  }
})
```

Essentially I have three variables for the query. I'm querying for posts with a `likeCount` between two of the numbers, and then greater than the third number.

Here are three example variables for the query:

```
var floor = 10, ceiling = 20, cursor = 0
```

When I write the query with the expressions in this order,

```
Post.find({
  likeCount: {
    $gte: floor,
    $lte: ceiling,
    $gte: cursor
  }
})
```

What I'm expecting to happen is any `Post` with a `likeCount` of 0 is omitted from the search results because they would be filtered out by the first expression of the query, in this case `$gte: 10`. Instead I'm getting incorrect results, such as a `Post` with a `likeCount` of 0 included.

However, when I just switch the order of expressions, like so:

```
Post.find({
  likeCount: {
    $gte: cursor
    $gte: floor,
    $lte: ceiling,
  }
})
```

Then I start getting correct results. My question is why is this happening? From my understanding of the documentation there's a short-circuiting effect with the AND operation in MongoDB. Why would it matter that the expressions are in a certain order? If a document's field doesn't pass one of the expressions, no matter in what order, shouldn't that document be excluded from the results?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is related to MongoDB's implicit AND, but how you are defining the filter. The `$gte` field is defined twice, so the second value overwrites the first. Here's an example:

```js
x = { $gte: 0, $lte: 20, $gte: 10 }
console.log(x)
```

As you can see, the second value for `$gte` is the one that remains.

Instead, we can take a look at what range of values actually matters, given the three variables, `floor`, `cursor`, and `ceiling`.

You want to find posts where `floor <= likeCount <= ceiling`, and `cursor <= likeCount`.

Let's say `cursor <= floor`. Because `cursor` is less than or equal to `floor`, you can guarantee that `likeCount` is greater than `cursor` AND between `floor` and `ceiling` with a filter of `{ likeCount: { $gte: floor, $lte: ceiling }}`.

If `cursor > floor`, then a filter of `{ likeCount: { $gte: cursor, $lte: ceiling }}` would work.

Keeping this in mind, you could do something like this:

```
Post.find({
  likeCount: {
    $gte: cursor <= floor ? floor : cursor,
    $lte: ceiling,
  }
})
```

Comment: This actually might have inadvertently given me the answer. Implicit AND with commas doesn't work when the same expression is being used more than once. In the docs they use the $or operator in the example, here it's $gte. That's partially what you're pointing out and I just wasn't seeing it. +1 for leading me to the right answer.